Replace Trigger in Teradata SQL Assistant
I'm trying to create a table that will keep an updated column of run dates for each table in a database. I created the Database_Update table with three fields: Updated, Table_Name, Run_Dt. The Updated column will be either Yes or No, depending on the Run_Dt and CURRENT_DATE.
I have tried a variety of different ways on the following trigger statement, but no matter what, I get a syntax error saying something like an 'END' keyword between string or a Unicode character literal and ')'. Please help!
REPLACE TRIGGER Database_Update_Trigger
AFTER INSERT ON Air_Table
REFERENCING NEW AS New_Row
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Database_Update (Updated, Table_Name, Run_Dt)
VALUES ((case when month(air_table.run_dt) >= month(current_date) and year(air_table.run_dt) >= year(current_date) then 'Yes' else 'No'), 'Air_Table', air_table.run_dt);
END;

You appear to be missing the END keyword for the CASE expression -  between the character literal ('No') and the closing  ) around the expression.

Additional remark: Table-level triggers will perform better for multi row Inserts
